# Background color not showing in print preview IE

Tags: html, css, angularjs, internet-explorer, printing

How can i make sure IE would print the circles?

im currently using this:

```
<li ng-repeat="items in ferdigheter">{{ items.title}}
<div class="circles">
    <div class="circle" ng-repeat="a in thisnumber(items.stars)"></div>
    <div class="empty_circle" ng-repeat="a in thisnumber(items.maxstars - items.stars)"></div>

</div>
</li>
```

When im viewing whats beeing printed (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd>) the title  is there, but the circles / empty circle is not ther in the print. any idea why?

How can i make sure that the circle`s will be printed too?

current page:

[image]

current print:

[image]

wanted print:

[image]

update:

scope:

```
  $scope.ferdigheter = [
        {tittel: 'Adobe Photoshop', stars: 2, maxstars: 5},
        {tittel: 'CSS/html', stars: 5, maxstars: 5},
        {tittel: 'PHP', stars: 4, maxstars: 5},
        {tittel: 'Angular', stars: 3, maxstars: 5},
        {tittel: 'Javascript', stars: 4, maxstars:5},
        {tittel: 'MS Word', stars: 4, maxstars: 5},
        {tittel: 'Dreamviewer', stars: 2, maxstars: 5},
        {tittel: 'Phpstorm', stars: 4, maxstars: 5},
        {tittel: 'Codeigniter', stars: 5, maxstars: 5},
        {tittel: 'XXX', stars: 3, maxstars: 5},
        {tittel: 'XXX', stars: 5, maxstars: 5},

    ];
```

Scope `thisnumber` Creates an array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In IE go to File > page setup  one window will popup

there is option "print background color and images" make sure u select that
and try

[image]

Comment: I don't have that kind of layout. Anyway I can print in colors, instead of black and white , but I can't find the option you are suggesting

Comment: In IE 11, there is little change in navigation: goto Print > Page Setup. There you can see a checkbox with "Print background color and images" title. Select it and you can see background color and images. :)